# i wrote my view code in controller page to fetch data from database, but my script is not working in that code

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I wrote my view code in the controller page to fetch data from the database, but my script is not working in that code.
I want to when the user click on the radio button then the profile section is hidden and the course section will be shown.

[image]

Controller Code :

```
if(array_sum($arrCount)==0)
{
  echo '<div class="chat-message-div">
        <div class="chat-message" style="color:red;">
        Sorry I cant recognize you.Please provide a bit more details
        </div>
        </div>'; 
  exit; 
}
else
{
    $max = $arrCount[0];
    $indicate = 0;
    for($i=1;$i<count($arrCount);$i++)
    {
        if($arrCount[$i]>$max)
        {
            $max = $arrCount[$i];
            $indicate = $i;
        }
    }

    echo '<div class="chat-message-div">
            <div class="chat-message">
                '.$arr[$indicate]['answer'].'
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" id="msg6" name="q6" value="'.$arr[$indicate]['option1'].'">'.$arr[$indicate]['option1'].'</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" id="msg6" name="q6" value="'.$arr[$indicate]['option2'].'">'.$arr[$indicate]['option2'].'</label>
                </div>

                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" id="msg6" name="q6" value="'.$arr[$indicate]['option3'].'">'.$arr[$indicate]['option3'].'</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" id="msg6" name="q6" value="'.$arr[$indicate]['option4'].'">'.$arr[$indicate]['option4'].'</label>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        ';

    exit;
}
```

javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('input[name="q6"]').on('click', function() { 
            var test = $(this).val(); 
            $('.profile').hide(); 
            $("#user-profile").hide(); 
            $('.courses').show(); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: where is the javascript part?

Comment: PHP Codeigiter Framework

Comment: Script Code : <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="q6"]').on('click', function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
          $('.profile').hide();
        $("#user-profile").hide();
       $('.courses').show();
    });
});

</script>

Comment: Writing view in controller is a complete violation of MVC design pattern convention. As you are using codeigniter, which is a MVC based Framework so please try to follow the standard convention first.

Comment: @ArifulIslam i fetch data from database a/c to previous data, so i wrote in controller..

Comment: @PriyaKumariSah can you get the value of `var test = $(this).val();` ???

Comment: @KUMAR when i write simply in view page then it works but when i write in controller page then it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better of sending your data along to your view.

(From the top of my head) you can call `$this->load->view('[VIEWNAMEHERE], $arr);`

Then in your view file you can just use normal HTML and insert the php values in the correct places. That would look something like this:

```
<div class="chat-message-div">
    <div class="chat-message">
        <?php echo $arr[$indicate]['answer']; ?>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" id="msg6" name="q6" value="<?php echo $arr[$indicate]['option1'];?>">
                    <?php echo $arr[$indicate]['option1'];?>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" id="msg6" name="q6" value="<?php echo $arr[$indicate]['option2'];?>">
                    <?php echo $arr[$indicate]['option2'];?>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" id="msg6" name="q6" value="<?php echo $arr[$indicate]['option3'];?>">
                    <?php echo $arr[$indicate]['option3'];?>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" id="msg6" name="q6" value="<?php echo $arr[$indicate]['option4'];?>">
                    <?php echo $arr[$indicate]['option4'];?>
                </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('input[name="q6"]').on('click', function() { 
            var test = $(this).val(); 
            $('.profile').hide(); 
            $("#user-profile").hide(); 
            $('.courses').show(); 
        }); 
     }); 
</script>
```

Don't forget to store your view as a .php file

Haven't tested any of this but this is kind of how you should handle something like this.